# recurrence relation for $n$-digit quaternary sequences

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Find a system of recurrence relations for computing the number of $n$-digit quaternary sequences with

(a) An even number of $0$s

(b) An even total number of $0$s and $1$s

(c) an even number of $0$s and an even number of $1$s

I am stuck on all parts of this problem. I have tried looking up solutions to this question and I am having trouble understand the rationale behind it.

For (a) I have attempted it:

When $n=2$, the number of sequences with an even number of $0$s is just one sequence: $00$

When $n=3$, the sequences can be: $001,002,003,010,020,030,100,200,300$: $9$ sequences

When $n=4$: the structures can be $00--, -00-,--00, 0-0-,0--0,$ or $-0-0$ and the sequence $0000$. For all the different structures there is a total of $3^2$ sequences so there are $6\times 3^2=54$ sequences. So when $n=4$ there are $54+1=55$ sequences.

I am not sure that this approach is right but it is my attempt and if it is correct then I am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: Zero is an even number, so a sequence with no $0$s has an even number of $0$ so I would say you've overlooked $81$ sequences of length $4$ with an even number of $0$s, for example.

Comment: @saulspatz ive researched this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029944/find-a-system-of-recurrence-relations-foe-computing-the-number-of-n-digit-quater/1038227#1038227) i know that is a solution...i do not understand this solution at all. even looking at it and trying to derive the answer i cannot do.

Comment: Consider a sequence of length $n$ with an even number of $0$s.  If the last digit is $1,2,$ or $3,$ then there must be an even number of $0$s among the first $n-1$ digits.  If the last digit is $0,$ then there must be an odd number of digits among the first $n-1$ digits.  This is where the formula $a_n=3a_{n−1}+b_{n−1}$ comes from.  Is it clearer now?

Comment: yes! thank you +1 @saulspatz

Comment: @saulspatz can you walk me through the solution for (c)

Comment: I'm too sleepy right now.  Think about it, and if you still don't see it, write another comment tomorrow and I'll answer.

Comment: so far i have that: for $a_n$ if there is an even number of $0$s and $1$s and there is a $2$ or $3$ as the last digit then there is an even number of $0$s among the first $n-1$ digits. if the last digit is a $0$ or a $1$ then there is a odd number of $0$s or $1$s. so this is $a_n=2a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}$. for $b_n$ if there is an even number of $0$s and an odd number of $1s$ in the first $n-1$ digits and the last digit is a $2$ or a $3$ then it is simply $2b_{n-1}$. if the last digit it is a $0$ or $1$ this is where i get stuck. @saulspatz

Comment: @saulspatz if there is an even number of $0$s and an odd number of $1$s in the first $n-1$ digits and the last digit is a $1$ then it becomes $even-even$ and if the last digit is a $1$ then it becomes $odd-odd$. so shouldn't the formula be $b_n=2b_{n-1}+a_{n-1}+c_{n-1}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of $n-$digit sequences with an even number of both $0$s and $1$s, let $c_n$ be the number of $n-$digit sequences with an odd number of both $0$s and $1$s, and let $b_n$ be the number of $n-$digit sequences with an even number of one and an odd number of the other.  As stated in [Find a system of recurrence relations foe computing the number of n-digit quaternary sequences with](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029944/find-a-system-of-recurrence-relations-foe-computing-the-number-of-n-digit-quater/1038227#1038227), we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_n &=& 2a_{n-1} + b_{n-1} \tag{1}\\
b_n &=& 2a_{n-1} + 2b_{n-1} + 2c_{n-1}\tag{2} \\
c_n &=& b_{n-1} + 2c_{n-1}. \tag{3}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
From your comments, I gather that you understand the reason for $(1)$ (and, I suppose $(3)$, since it's essentially the same,)but are stuck on $(2).$  I'll only discuss $(2),$ therefore.

To get an "odd-even" sequence of $n$ digits, we can

- add a $2$ or $3$ to an odd-even sequence of length $n-1$
- add a $0$ or a $1$ to an even-even sequence of length $n-1$
- add a $0$ or a $1$ to an odd-odd sequence of length $n-1$

This gives formula $(2)$, since there are no other ways to construct an odd-even sequence of length $n-1$.

Your last comment doesn't make sense as written.  You say, "if there is an even number of $0$s and an odd number of $1$s in the first $n−1$ digits and the last digit is a $1$ then it becomes even−even and if the last digit is a $1$ then it becomes odd−odd."  This gives two contradictory results if the last digit is a $1.$  I suppose there's a typo, but the statement has nothing to do with the case any way.  Since we are looking for a formula for $b_n,$ we only care about how to make odd-even sequences.

You might find this table useful:$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
 &OO&OE&EO&EE\\ \hline
0&EO&EE&OO&OE\\ \hline
1&OE&OO&EE&EO\\ \hline
2&OO&OE&EO&EE\\ \hline
3&OO&OE&EO&EE\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Here $OO$ stands for "odd-odd," $EO$ for "even-odd," and so on.  Note that I've distinguished the case of an odd number of $0$ and an even number of $1$s from the case of an odd number of $1$ and an even number of $0$s.  The top row shows the kind of string of $n-1$ digits we have, and the table entries show what kind of $n-$digit string we get if the digit in the left-hand column is added.  Gathering together all these results, and then combining the odd-even and even-odd cases into one, will give all the recurrences.